# Having a problem with the connection between a python app and postgres db running in docker

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I am having trouble trying to make queries to a postgres db that is running in Docker.

As far as I can tell the database is connecting correctly using the psycopg2 library.

However when I execute a command and try to fetch the results, the results are empty. I can make the same query at the command line using psql and I get the expected results.

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

```
con = psycopg2.connect(
   host= 'localhost',
   port= '5432',
   database= 'daystarr',
   user= 'postgres',
   password= 'admin',
)

print('Connected to Postgres Database')

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM tickets')

rows = cur.fetchall()
for r in rows:
   print(r)

print(cur.fetchone())
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Here is the result when I run in command line:

[image]

`cur.fetchall()` returns `nothing` and `cur.fetchone()` returns `None`.

The other thing is that when I try to execute the command `CREATE TABLE tickets (ticket_id INT PRIMARY KEY;)`

[image]

I get a duplicate table error. So it must be connecting to the table. Thanks in advance!

Here is what it looks like when I just `print(cur.fetchall())`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is a weird edge case but if you are looking at this in the future I have found what the problem was. I had a version of PostgreSQL installed and apparently listening on port 5432. My docker container was exposing this port also. So basically my app must have been taking priority on my local machine install. I uninstalled PostgreSQL from my local machine and it found the Docker container immediately. Thank you for anyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `;` in your query, it should be

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tickets;")
```

Comment: Whoops, I did miss that but I am getting the same result.Thanks.

Comment: Try double quotes instead of single quotes in the query

Comment: Same issue using double quotes.

Comment: I added the error when trying to create a table. There is no error when just trying to query the table.

Comment: Print the cur.fetchall() response, you should get something like this

`
>>> cur.fetchall()
[(6, 42, 'foo'), (7, 74, 'bar')]
`
I would also try to replace with fetchone(), to debug the issue

Comment: I updated question for print(cur.fetchall()) and when i do print(fetchone()) I just get the same thing but instead of an empty list, I get None returned.

Comment: This is driving me insane because I really need to make this happen, and I can't find anything that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Very strange. I just closed the Docker container and con = psycopg2.connect() is still working.

Comment: That really suspicious, try a `netstat -ant` to see if port 5432 is open. Do you have another Postrgres installed outside of docker container?